# Usar Arraylist dentro de un SetOnclickListener

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy tratando de no escribir código repetitivo. Lo he logrado con algunas cosas pero se me complica conseguirlo dentro de un setOnclicklistener.
El codigo que quiero simplificar es el siguiente:

```
    b2decibeles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b2decibeles.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mDatabase.child("serie1").child("codigo1").child(Lugar).child("alertas").child("decibeles").setValue(0);

            }
        });

    b2humo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b2humo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mDatabase.child("serie1").child("codigo1").child(Lugar).child("alertas").child("humo").setValue(0);

        }
    });
```

Trato de simplificarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
          ArrayList<ImageButton> alerta;    //pone las crucesitas avisando que variable pasó el límite.
    alerta = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
    alerta.add(b2decibeles);
    alerta.add(b2humo);
    alerta.add(b2oxigeno);
    alerta.add(b2presion);
    alerta.add(b2humedad);
    alerta.add(b2obstruido);
    alerta.add(b2manipulado);

    final ArrayList<String> Variables;
    Variables = new ArrayList<String>();
    Variables.add("decibeles");
    Variables.add("humo");
    Variables.add("oxigeno");
    Variables.add("presion");
    Variables.add("humedad");
    Variables.add("obstruido");
    Variables.add("manipulado");

    for (int i = 0; i < alerta.size(); i++) {


        alerta.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alerta.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mDatabase.child("serie1").child("codigo1").child(Lugar).child("alertas").child(Variables.get(i)).setValue(0);

            }
        });
```

Pero me arroja error en el segundo "alerta" y en la "i".
He hecho varios programas pero no soy programador así que no se la teoría. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Qué error? Está bien indicar el código, pero sin un [mre] es imposible que podamos adivinar el error que te da. Por favor edita la pregunta y añade el error exacto que te da.

Comment: Es muy importante agregar que error indica.